# Add "open in browser" link to the profile page of the app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Sometimes amount of information in the profile page of any user in app is not enough. Currently to open profile in web while I'm in app I need to open any post where that user has been participated, open it in browser and using full site web go to the profile page.

Is it possible to add link like exists in post:

> [image: chrome]

to the profile page in the iOS app:

> [image: profile]

?